# Having URL troubles with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’ve been struggling using [this](http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-account-in-codeigniter/) guide a bit. I’ve followed every step exactly but I’m still running into errors.
I’m using a XAMPP server but when I type the url: “http://localhost/codeigniter/user_authentication”, I get a 404.
I made sure all the paths and everything are correct but I still run into the same error.
When I set the default_controller to User_authentication, it does correctly lead me to the page, but how can I access it directly via URL?

Thanks!

Comment: post your code with question

Comment: All the code is in the guide I linked, I downloaded their source code. I doubt it has something to do with the source code though since it comes directly from the guide and I haven't altered it. I'm new to the MVC model so It's probably something obvious I'm not seeing.

Comment: .htaccess `RewriteBase /codeigniter`

Comment: So I had it working on my localhost, but google wouldnt redirect to localhost. Now I'm trying it on a server hosted by my school which I have my own domain on. Now I keep running into ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when I try to navigate to the user_authentication. Could this be server-side? I just copy-pasted the CodeIgniter files from my XAMPP into my domain and changed the base url.

Comment: What happens when you include the index.php into the URL?
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/user_authentication

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem when using XAMPP. Now, however, when I'm using a public domain I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE using the same URL. It's no 404 so it does find the file but something else seems to go wrong. I tried it in different browsers and none work. Could it be server side?